# OneDrive, can you migrate shared locations from one computer to another?

Tags: windows, powershell, migration, user-management, usmt

We are migrating users to new computer, and they have around 10 different SharePoint sites. Is there a way to copy the settings to a new computer, without manually doing so.

I've looked at Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\OneDrive\Accounts\Business1
but that doesn't do anything when you migrate the hive to a new machine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I had not yet found a nice solution, so I would like to see if someone knows a hack or work around